# How can I make a NSTextView use a specific NSTextStorage?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview, nstextstorage

Is there a way set an NSTextView's `textStorage` property to my own NSTextStorage? You can customize the NSTextContainer, so is there a way to do something like this:

```
NSTextView *myTV = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGFrameMake(0,0,100,100) 
                                    withTextStorage:myTextStorage];
```

If not, is there a way to swap out the default text storage after the text view is instantiated? Does this need to be done by subclassing NSTextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than simply replacing the string in the storage, it doesn't seem like there's a way to replace the NSTextStorage object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Set the attributed string in the text storage.

```
[[myTV textStorage] setAttributedString:myTextStorage];
```

Comment: But isn't that just replacing the NSTextStorage's string and not the NSTextStorage object itself?

Comment: Well I did that before and it worked so.. Since NSTextStorage is a subclass of NSAttributedString I assumed it work. Try it out and see if it fits the functionality you require.